# How to make scrollable single line td for html table

Tags: html, css

I think it simple question but unfortunately I don't know how to scroll long text of < td > instead of new line or hide some part of texts

my html code is:

```
<table [border]="1" style="width:100%; table-layout:fixed;">
  <tr>
    <td>
       Short text.
    </td>
    <td>
       Long text. Long text. Long text. Long text. Long text. Long text. Long text. 
    </td>
    <td>
       Long text. Long text. Long text. Long text. Long text. Long text. Long text. 
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Edit:

This css make single line td but it hide the long texts

```
td{
   padding:5px;
   width:100%;
   overflow: scroll;
   white-space:nowrap;
   //text-overflow: ellipsis;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `overflow: hidden` overridden the scrollbar.

```css
td {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table [border]="1" style="width:100%; table-layout:fixed;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Short text.
    </td>
    <td>
      Long text. Long text. Long text. Long text. Long text. Long text. Long text.
    </td>
    <td>
      Long text. Long text. Long text. Long text. Long text. Long text. Long text.
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks .. as i see the 1st long text become on the 2nd long text so its not perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. Try scrolling 2nd and 3rd cell.

**For vertical scrolling :**

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr{
  display: flex;
}

td {
  width: 33.33%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table [border]="1" style="width:100%; table-layout:fixed;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Short text.
    </td>
    <td>
      Long text. Long text. Long text. Long text. Long text. Long text. Long text.
    </td>
    <td>
      Long text. Long text. Long text. Long text. Long text. Long text. Long text.
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**For horizontal scrollling :**

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  width: 33.33%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table [border]="1" style="width:100%; table-layout:fixed;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Short text.
    </td>
    <td>
      Long text. Long text. Long text. Long text. Long text. Long text. Long text.
    </td>
    <td>
      Long text. Long text. Long text. Long text. Long text. Long text. Long text.
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks. i think vertical scrolling is the best answer but let wait few hours for some other answers